# Hard Millikan Integral

Tags: integration, physics, indefinite-integrals

I tried to solve the Millikan integer, but I did not success. The initial integer is:
$$m\frac{dv}{dt}= \frac{4}{3}\pi a^3 \rho g - qE - 6\pi \eta av$$ 
and I must prove show I to optain this: 
$$v= \frac{\frac{4}{3}\pi a^3 \rho g - qE} {6\pi \eta a}\left(1-e^\left(\frac{-6\pi \eta at}{m}\right)\right) $$

*** Just to make sure, all the "greek variables" are not variables in this equation; only $v$ and $t$.

%%%________________________________________________________%%%

Those are my steps:

$$\int\frac{dv}{4/3 * \pi a^3 \rho g - qE - 6\pi \eta a v} = \int\frac{dt}{m}$$

---

My substitution:
$$u=4/3 * \pi a^3 \rho g - qE - 6\pi \eta a v$$
$$du= -6\pi \eta a (dv)$$
$$dv= \frac{-du}{6\pi \eta a}$$

---

$$-\int\frac{du}{6\pi \eta a (u)} = \frac{t}{m} +c$$
$$\frac{-1}{6\pi \eta a} \ln \left\lvert  4/3 * \pi a^3 \rho g - qE - 6\pi \eta a v\right\rvert = \frac{t}{m} +c$$

$$ c=\frac{-1}{6\pi \eta a} \ln \left\lvert  4/3 * \pi a^3 \rho g - qE\right\rvert$$ We know that $t$ and $v$ are equal to 0.

$$-m \ln \left\lvert  4/3 * \pi a^3 \rho g - qE - 6\pi \eta a v\right\rvert= 6\pi \eta avt*\ln \left\lvert  4/3 * \pi a^3 \rho g - qE\right\rvert$$

$$ \ln \left\lvert \left( 4/3 * \pi a^3 \rho g - qE - 6\pi \eta a v \right)^{-m}\right\rvert= 6\pi \eta avt*\ln \left\lvert  4/3 * \pi a^3 \rho g - qE\right\rvert$$

$$\ln \left\lvert \frac{4/3 * \pi a^3 \rho g - qE}{\left( 4/3 * \pi a^3 \rho g - qE - 6\pi \eta a v \right)^{m}}\right\rvert = 6\pi \eta at$$

This is my last step, I don't know how to solve for v. Just in case, could you just make sure that I did not any mistakes so far and help me to solve for v. This should be the  final answer:
$$v= \frac{\frac{4}{3}\pi a^3 \rho g - qE} {6\pi \eta a}\left(1-e^\left(\frac{-6\pi \eta at}{m}\right)\right) $$

Comment: If $v$ and $t$ are the only variables, then how about grouping some of the constants together just for ease of reading? $m\frac{dv}{dt}=A-Bv$. Also it isn't clear what substitution you made $u=?$

Comment: @snulty I tried to make is faster to write!!! I Will identify my substitution.

Comment: I'm just saying to pick those letters because the answer you're looking for seems to be $v=\frac{A}{B}\left(1-e^{-Bt/m}\right)$. It would've just been tidier is all.

Comment: @snulty Is this a "known" answer in advanced Mathematic?

Comment: I've skipped some steps, but hopefully you can fill them in. Also I can see now we made the same substitution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the equation as $$m\frac{dv}{dt}=A-Bv$$
one can solve by [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables). Re-write as:

$$\frac{m}{A-Bv}\frac{dv}{dt}=1$$

Integrating $dt$ and making the substitution $u=A-Bv$:

$$\frac{-m}{B}\int\frac{du}{u}=t+\text{constant}$$

Continuing:

$$\ln(A-Bv)=-\frac{Bt}{m}+\text{constant}$$

$$v=\frac{1}{B}\left(A-ce^{-Bt/m}\right)$$

Since you have mentioned that $v(0)=0$, then this implies that $c=A$ and thus:

$$v=\frac{A}{B}\left(1-e^{-Bt/m}\right)$$

Finally note that $A=\frac{4}{3}\pi a^3\rho g-qE$, and $B=6\pi\eta a$.

Comment: Could you show how to get rid of the $\ln$ between this step: $\ln (A−Bv)=−Bt/m +constant $ and this step: $v=1/B (A−ce^{−Bt/m} )$?

Comment: @Matt exponentiate both sides, and replace $e^{\text{constant}}$ by the letter $c$, another constant. That and $e^{-Bt/m+\text{constant}}=e^{-Bt/m}e^{\text{constant}}$

Comment: I am not able to solve for v in this equation: $\frac{A}{Bv} = ce^{-Bt/m}$

Comment: $e^{\ln(A-Bv)}=A-Bv$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
m\,\totald{\mrm{v}\pars{t}}{t} & = {4 \over 3}\,\pi a^{3}\rho g - qE -
6\pi\eta a\mrm{v}\pars{t}\implies
\pars{\totald{}{t} + {1 \over \tau}}\mrm{v}\pars{t} = {\tilde{v} \over \tau}
\\[5mm] 
\mbox{where}\quad & 
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\tau} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{m \over 6\pi\eta a}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\tilde{v}} & \ds{\equiv} &
\ds{4\pi a^{3}\rho g/3 - qE \over 6\pi\eta a}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm]
\implies & = \totald{\bracks{\expo{t/\tau}\mrm{v}\pars{t}}}{t} =
{\tilde{v} \over \tau}\,\expo{t/\tau}
\implies\expo{t/\tau}\mrm{v}\pars{t} - \expo{t_{0}/\tau}v\pars{t_{0}} =
{\tilde{v} \over \tau}\,\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\expo{t'/\tau}\,\dd t' 
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\mrm{v}\pars{t}} & =
v\pars{t_{0}}\expo{-\pars{t - t_{0}}/\tau} +
{\tilde{v} \over \tau}\,\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\expo{-\pars{t - t'}/\tau}\,\dd t' =
\color{#f00}{v\pars{t_{0}}\expo{-\pars{t - t_{0}}/\tau} +
\tilde{v}\bracks{1 - \expo{-\pars{t - t_{0}}/\tau}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, this is too complex for me!